# Finding the cardinality of a cartesian product of a set and a cartesian product.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A = \{0, 1, \{2, 3, 4\}\}$

$B = \{1, 5\}$

$C = B \times \mathbb{N}$

What is the cardinality of $A \times C$?

I know the enumeration of $A \times C$ is $\{(0,(1,0)), (0,(1,1)), (0,(1,2))\ldots (\text{infinite?})\}$, but I don't know how to write down the cardinality of it.

Comment: What is $D$? You did not mention it

Comment: Whoops I mean **A x C** Sorry. Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cardinality of a cartesian product is simply the product of the cardinalities, obeying rules which extend those for finite cardinalities.

If one cardinality is zero, the cartesian product has cardinality zero.

If one or both cardinalities is infinite and neither is zero, the cartesian product has cardinality equal to the greater of the two cardinalities.

And, of course, if both cardinalities are finite, the cardinality of the cartesian product is the arithmetic product of the cardinalities.

Answer (score 0):

A finite product of at most  denumerable sets is at most denumerable, and if one of them is denumerable, the products is denumerable. Hence the answer is $\,\aleph_0$.